# how to run local HTML, css, js file in react native IOS side

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

This is my app.js file code but I can not unable to load it in IOS when i try this tree file in root of the project then HTMLl file is run but CSS and js is not working so I tried in natively but still not working this Resources folder added from Xcode and after trying this path "require('./ios/Resources/pic.html')" but not work so please give me proper solution ho to load this three file in React-Native

```
<WebView     
style={{ flex: 1, }}
originWhitelist={["*"]}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}  
source={require('./ios/Resources/pic.html')} />
```

`

thanks.

i expecting I load Local HTML, css and Js file in webview from IOS side in React-Native.